# doing multiple ajax request but response always the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make multiple request to store different profiles from a website on one array.
But on safari i keep getting the same profile as the response for my requests . on the other browsers is working fine.

...

```
for(let i=0;i<12;i++){   
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://randomuser.me/api",
      }).done(function(data) {
        profiles.push(data);
      });
}
```

...

this is what i am getting but every profile should be different
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnfzW.png

what can i do to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on all other browsers it might be a caching issue.

You don't need to make 12 calls to the API you can just fetch the amount you need by changing the `results` in the API call.

Here is an example that prints 12 names:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://randomuser.me/api?results=12",
}).done(function(data) {
    data.results.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user.name.first);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but still not working . with that code i get the same profile 12 times

Comment: Can you run the code I provided and tell me what gets printed in the console? Cause I have no idea why would randomuser.me return the same user from a single query.

Comment: sorry mate my bad, your code just fixed the problem. I was push data into the array instead of 'user'. Thanks for the help